# How to get specified user offline message from openfire and keep others stored?

Tags: web, chat, openfire, strophe.js

Openfire uses ofoffline table to store user offline message, but as long as user is online, openfire will push all offline message to the user automatically,no matter the offline message is the user’s or not. So the question is, how to push specified user offline message to the user, still the offline messages are not pushed can still store in the offline table, and next time the user ask those offline messages,they can get delivered?

By the way,I am using strophejs to develop a web chat.

Comment: I can't help with strophe.js, however, when you CONNECT to Openfire, you can send an unavailable Presence. If you do so, at LOGIN time Openfire will not send the offline messages. After login phase just send the correct Presence (available OR the user chosed one) and then retreive it manually asking in same request to not delete the messages. Look for XEP-13 https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html

Comment: thanks very much,I will try it.